# multiple nested has_many in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have the following `course.rb` model

```
has_many :chapters
  has_many :lectures, through: :chapters
  has_many :enrols
  has_many :contents, through: :lectures
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :enrols
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :chapters, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lectures, allow_destroy: true
```

and `course.rb` active admin file

```
form title: 'Edit Course' do |f|
    f.inputs 'Details' do
      f.input :course_name
      f.input :course_subtitle
      f.input :course_description
      f.input :video_link
      f.input :course_language
      f.input :status
      f.input :course_image
    end

    # has_many :contents do |content|
    #   content.input :description
    #   content.input :attachment
    # end

    f.has_many :chapters, allow_destroy: true do |chapter|
      # chapter.input :title
      chapter.has_many :lectures do |lecture|
        # lecture.input :title
        # lecture.has_many :contents do |content|
        #   content.input :description
        # end
        lecture.input :title
      end
    end
    actions
  end
```

I am trying to make the `content` of `course` editable in the course form and it wud require multiple nested has_many since it has number of has_many through relation.

Right now I get `undefined method`new_record?' for nil:NilClass` error

How can it be done? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method new_record?' for nil:NilClass`

**Root cause:**

```
chapter.has_many :lectures do |lecture|
```

**Reason:**

You have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :lectures, allow_destroy: true` in `Course` model, so you **can't have a nested lecture** inside `Chapter`

**Solution:**

```
chapter.has_many :lectures do |lecture|
```

should be

```
f.has_many :lectures do |lecture|
```

If you want to have *nested lecture* inside `chapter`, then remove `accepts_nested_attributes_for :lectures, allow_destroy: true` from `Course` model and add it inside `Chapter` model.

> What if i want to add only the lecture? Your suggestion seem to work
>   but it gave me option to add lecutre and chapter

In that case, there is no need for `f.has_many :chapters, allow_destroy: true do |chapter|`. Just have `f.has_many :lectures do |lecture|`

Comment: what if i want to add only the lecture? Your suggestion seem to work but it gave me option to add lecutre and chapter

Comment: @SushantBajracharya Then just remove `f.has_many :chapters, allow_destroy: true do |chapter|` and have `f.has_many :lectures do |lecture|`

Comment: getting this issue `Cannot modify association 'Course#contents' because it goes through more than one other association.` any idea

Comment: @SushantBajracharya It is something to do with associations. I suggest you to add another explaining the error. So that your question gets enough attention.

Comment: got it working , do u know how i can remove the add new content btn ? I just want it for update purpose so I want to remove add new content btn below the form